# Collection return value from key

Tags: vba

I am having issues returning a value from a collection using the key.

The GetPercentsUpdateCharts sub is creating a new collection and placing a new value into it with key {{percentOpen}} and value "Test".

The Contains function written with Debug.Print is outputting true which proves the key exists in the collection.

The Retrieve function always returns "Not Found".

Where did I go wrong with this?

```
Private Sub GetPercentsUpdateCharts()
    Set colPercentTokens = Nothing
    Set colPercentTokens = New Collection

    'Calculate Percents and Update Charts
    Store colPercentTokens, "{{percentOpen}}", "Test"
    Debug.Print Contains(colPercentTokens, "{{percentOpen}}")
    Debug.Print Retrieve(colPercentTokens, "{{percentOpen}}")
End Sub

Public Function Contains(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo NotFound
    Dim itm As Object

    Set itm = col(key)
    Contains = True

MyExit:
    Exit Function

NotFound:
    Contains = False
    Resume MyExit

End Function

Public Function Retrieve(col As Collection, key As String) As String
    On Error GoTo NotFound
    Dim itm As Object

    Set itm = col(key)
    Retrieve = CStr(itm)
MyExit:
    Exit Function

NotFound:
    Retrieve = "Not Found"
    Resume MyExit

End Function

Public Sub Store(col As Collection, k As String, v As String)
    Dim kv As Object

    If (Contains(col, k)) Then
        Set kv = col(k)
        kv.value = v
    Else
        Set kv = New KeyValue
        kv.Init k, v
        col.Add kv, k
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You may find using a scripting.dictionary is easier as this object has a built in 'exists' method.  You will need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime to enable the use of Scripting.dictionaries with intellisense.

Comment: Looks like you have your keys/values flipped... I think (since you didn't post the full code) that "{{percentOpen}}" is the value, not the key